# Scroll down to target when you begin to scroll

Tags: jquery

This is what I want to do: If you are at the top of the page and start to scroll down, you should automatically scroll down to the div #content. If I use the code below then I can't use animated scroll to my other links on the page and I can't scroll at all after the page has scroll down to #content with the code below.

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
    var content = $('#content');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: content.offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Are you looking for anything of that sort? http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage

Comment: So you mean you need to know when a scroll starts and what the current offset is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two version here, pick brother.

**1.**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1) {
        $(this).bind('DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
            if (e.originalEvent.detail > 0) {
                $('html, body').delay(200).animate({
                    scrollTop: $('#content').offset().top
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $(this).bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
            if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 < 1) {
                $('html, body').delay(200).animate({
                    scrollTop: $('#content').offset().top
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/anthonypagaycarbon/whywntnp/)*** my version

**2 .**

```
var scrolling = false;    

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ( $(window).scrollTop() <= 100 && scrolling === false) {
            //set to true to prevent multiple scrolls
            scrolling = true; 

            //run the animation 
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('#content').offset().top
            }, 1000, function() {
                //when animation is complete, set scrolling to false
                scrolling = false; 
            });
        }

    });
});
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k4vmqwpr/)*** from sir [Erikk Ross](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18772/erikk-ross)

Comment: Thanks. Version 1 works in chrome and Safari but not in Firefox.

Comment: Try this brother [http://jsfiddle.net/anthonypagaycarbon/cswnzjfd/](http://jsfiddle.net/anthonypagaycarbon/cswnzjfd/). I also tested it in IE, FF, working properly. Script on version 1 is updated also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
     $("a").click(function(e){     
         e.preventDefault();      
         $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1000); 
    });
});
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/anthonypagaycarbon/yt4rkeqh/)***

Comment: I forgot to say that I have a menu in the #content. The links do not work if i add this jquery code. I cant scroll at all when i come down to #content. And I use this to the menu links: $("nav ul li a").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
  var target = $( $(this).attr('href') );
 $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
 return false;
});

Comment: What is the structure of your a tags ? someting like this ? `<a href="#content">Content</a>`

Comment: Yes I have that structure of my links.

Comment: I updated my answer above bro .. try if correct. Hope that helps on you .

Comment: No sorry. That is how my menu links work with the click. But I want to scroll down to #content if you are at the top of the page and you start to scroll down. And then the menu links should work as usual with the click.

Comment: I think you need something like this [http://jsfiddle.net/JAy7Y/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/JAy7Y/1/).